# Carousel materialize não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Estou usando o código de inicialização padrão do materialize , mas não funciona

Carousel

```html
<div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
  </div>
```

```js
    /* inicializacao */

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, options);
  });
```

<sup>[Screenshot da IDE com o código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YZx8.png)</sup>

Comment: Bom dia, Antes de qualquer coisa, comece fazendo o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a comunidade funciona; depois leia o guia de [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta.
Poste seu código completo e para que possa ser ajudado e irá ajudar outros no futuro.

Answer (score 1):

Então, como pode ver no exemplo abaixo, funciona perfeitamente. **O problema:** você simplesmente copiou o código da documentação, e a documentação é para demonstrar como as coisas são feitas e o que você pode fazer. Repare que na imagem que você colocou na pergunta está igual da documentação, mas, **aquele `options` é para demonstrar que você pode inserir as opções para o carousel e não simplesmente colocar a palavra option lá e pronto. Provavelmente se você abrir o console do navegador que utiliza verá um erro, exatamente por esse option que não existe**.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
  var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="carousel">
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
</div>
```

> **Dica:** Primeiro aprenda a base (Html, Css e Javascript) e depois parta para esses frameworks de CSS (Bootstrap, Materialize, etc..) e Javascript.